# TypeScript - React pass Component as generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, components

I'm trying to pass a component to base component as a generic.
I know how to do that as props, but I'm trying to do that as a generic.

What I want to do:

```
class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent<SomeComponent> {...}
```

and in the `ParentComponent` I want to render the `SomeComponent`:

```
class ParentComponent<T> extends Component<React.ComponentProps<T>> {

   render() {
      return <T {...this.props}>
   }

}
```

But I can't make it to work.
Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think this `<T {...this.props}>` is possible because using the passed type as a component will not work.

Comment: @RameshReddy Thanks! Yes. It doesn't work. so is there any TS way to make this possible?

Comment: If you're trying to create a HOC then the nested component should be passed as an argument. See [this](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb)

Comment: Thanks @RameshReddy . This is nice example, which I'm familiar with this pattern. but it's not what I'm looking for. first it's using FC and not using Generics.

Comment: It has an example with a class component. All the HOCs are using generics for passing the props but the nested component is passed as an argument because only types can be passed as generics.

Comment: @RameshReddy and isn't there a way to pass the component as type?

Comment: There's no use in passing the component's type, it only makes sense to pass the props type. Every component is either a functional or a class component.